# Raspberry Pi Zero MI-305 Mini USB Microphone with horrible background noise

Tags: pi-zero-w, microphone

I have been trying to use a mini USB microphone, mode MI-305 with my Raspberry Pi Zero W. However, when I try to play audio recorded from it, it has this very loud background noise like a square wave buzzing sound. I have tested this microphone on a MacBook Air, and it works perfectly. I am attempting to use speech recognition, and I really need the background noise gone.

Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this problem by using a different USB to Mini-USB adapter which covers the USB port. The problem was that RF noise was getting in. Just get the adapter to cover the actual metal part of the microphone and it should fix it!

Answer (score 0):

I disabled bluetooth completely and turned off the wifi when recording sound. Much better sound quality.